# Gradle build failing with many "unmappable character for encoding UTF-8" errors

Tags: intellij-idea, utf-8, gradle

I'm seeing many "unmappable character for encoding UTF-8" errors messages when I run a `gradle build` like this:

```
C:\5.0-Maint-New-Techs\src\com\avada\jms\base\JmsUtils.java:136: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
                ï¿½ You can use arrays as well as primitive types for the values.
```

When I go to the lines that are flagged this way, they look perfectly fine in my editor.  Not sure if this is a `gradle` or `idea` issue...any ideas on how to get around these errors?

Comment: What's the encoding of the `.java` file?

Comment: Maybe `ANSI`???  At least that's what it says when I open it in Notepad++

Comment: @Makoto - I think your comment is pointing me down the right track...think I need to update file encodings in `idea`

Comment: That's probably it.  I've only ever had my Java files opened in UTF-8 mode before (but I remember this sort of torture with I18N files).

Answer (score 0):

Please change the non-ascii characters to double quotes(") or any other character(this is basically work around solution of the problem). This problem will be resolved. I think this issue is due to intellij.